# Why do some A380 main wheels have no brakes?

Tags: aircraft-design, landing-gear, airbus-a380

The A380 has 20 main and 2 nose wheels. Apparently the nose wheels have no brakes (compare with [Are there any aircraft with a nose wheel braking system?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/are-there-any-aircraft-with-a-nose-wheel-braking-system)).

While researching for this question ([How are brakes cooled on heavy aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33716/how-are-brakes-cooled-on-heavy-aircraft/33717#33717)), I assumed that all of the 20 main wheels are braked. I looked at a few pictures of A380 landing gears. As far as I have seen, all main wheels are equipped with brake cooling fans (BCF), **except** the four rear wheels in the inner 6-wheeled  undercarriages. (e.g. [here](http://cdn-www.airliners.net/photos/airliners/2/0/9/1237902.jpg?v=v40)).

This picture below clearly shows that there is no brake unit inside the rim:

[image]

There is another picture [here](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/54/46/9c/54469c9ee9466ae9dde57872959d919f.jpg) whithout BCFs, but the same four wheels apparently have no brakes.

**What is the reason for omitting the brakes** at these four wheel positions?

Is this a common configuration, or quite unique to the A380?

Comment: I've got no facts for this, so a comment:
[Here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1166/why-is-heavy-braking-recommended-in-an-aircraft-with-carbon-fiber-brakes-in-or) you can read that carbon brakes have less wear when used to apply heavy braking forces. Perhaps some of the brakes are omitted, such that the others have to 'work harder' and thus, wear less?

Comment: Because it doesn't need them.  Why fit what's not needed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to this [presentation](https://www.arts-et-metiers.asso.fr/manifestation_cr/446_compte_rendu.pdf) by Claude Lelaie (Head of A380 test), the brakes of the A380 were tested before certification with 89 MJ, and after certification with 120 MJ.

According to your calculation [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/33717/17780) the RTO of an A380 sinks 1.7 GJ to the brakes.

Therefore either configuration would be sufficient with respect to the RTO energy:

- 20x  89 MJ = 1.78 GJ
- 16x 120 MJ = 1.92 GJ

It is not clear if this setup was planned from the beginning, or maybe the brake design turned out to be better than expected.

During braking, the vector sum of brake and weight forces is pointing forward. This means increase of force on the front wheels, and less force on the rear wheels. This is probably the reason why the engineers have chosen to omit the brakes on the 4 rearmost wheels, and not a different location.

Answer (score 17):

Because they are not needed (for the passenger variant). Addition of brakes increases the weight and complexity of the system, which is undesirable. Why add something that is not required?. If it is required, additional brakes can always be added, like in the (proposed) freighter version. [According to flightglobal.com](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/red-hot-a380-completes-heavyweight-brake-tests-212528/):

> Sixteen of the A380-800's 20 main wheels are braked, with the two aft wheels on each body landing gear of the passenger version not having brakes (unlike the freighter variant, where all 20 main wheels are braked due to its increased weights).

Also, Aft Axle of BLG is steerable to ensure better maneuverability for small radius turn (Body Wheel Steering); braking a steerable axle would require special linkages, increasing weight and complexity. This is not insurmountable, however- Boeing 777's landing gear is similar, but has brakes on all its wheels.

Comment: @bogl The 777 only has 12 main gear wheels (6 on each). The brakes on the A380 aren't needed because the aircraft's landing weight doesn't require that much braking force for the runways that it needs to land on. The freighter version would be different since presumably it would land at higher weights. Similarly the A380 doesn't have thrust reversers on the outboard engines either.

Comment: Out of curiosity: would the 'needed' braking force account for action of thrust reversers? (I'd imagine so under normal operation, but that the braking system could do the job in the event of failure at the cost of higher wear?)

Comment: @msanford The aircraft is required to be able to stop without the use of thrust reversers, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @RonBeyer I assume this to be the case. I guess that does make my question rather hair-splitting, since it's obvious that thrust reversal would reduce brake wear at least somewhat. Thanks!

Comment: @bogl The aircraft must be able to come to a complete stop from V1 on the remaining runway without the use of thrust reversers.

Comment: @bogl Your V1 speed will depend on the runway lenght. It is not a fixed value. So yes, any runway.

Comment: @J.Hougaard The shorter the runway, the lower V1, the easier for the plane to pass the RTO brake test? That cannot be.

Comment: @bogl The aircraft also needs to be able to take off on that runway because the tests are run at MTOW. There is no point in using a runway shorter than the certified MTOW requires.

Comment: @bogl The actual RTO certification test isnt done based on runway length, its done based on the maximum kinetic energy dissipation of the braking system the aircraft manufacturer wants the aircraft certified to.  Page 33 on https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/25-7B.pdf

Comment: @Moo Great! This is what I was looking for!

Comment: @J.Hougaard No, V1 does not depend on the runway length.