# A C130 lands on a carrier. How much energy must be dissipated and where does it all go?

Tags: landing, aircraft-carrier

[image]

Assumptions must be described and answers must be math justified. Extra credit for plausible obscurity.

[c130 carrier landing](https://youtu.be/EERe7XEPeuM?t=399)

update:
From the video the landing roll was 270ft at 85klb and 460ft at 121klb using upgraded antilock brakes and full reverse thrust.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arresting_gear

Comment: It's just a really, really big hydraulic shock absorber.

Comment: @Steve The C130 has no tailhook.

Comment: I didn't know that ... even after being deployed on a carrier!

Comment: Way too big a math assignment for me.

Comment: Downvotes with no comments? After all the complaints about the simplicity of the other one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kinetic energy to dissipate is easy to calculate:

$$ E_\text{kin} = \frac{1}{2} m \times \text{GS}^2 $$

Here, the ground speed GS must be w.r.t. to the carrier deck, not the sea.

The landing weight of the C-130 must be between the Operating Empty Weight ($\sim 75 \, 000 \, \text{lbs}$) and the Maximum Landing Weight ($\sim 130 \, 000 \, \text{lbs}$). These tests were performed at $85 \, 000 \, \text{lbs}$ and $121 \, 000 \, \text{lbs}$. To figure out the landing speed, we can look at this graph for full flaps from the [performance manual](https://www.docdroid.com/ZLTlxml/lockheed-c-130b-flight-manual-performance-data-pdf#page=266):

[image: Landing Speed]

We will use the touchdown speeds from the graph for the calculation, which are defined as

> The touchdown speeds presented in figures A8-1 and A8-2 are the initial speeds
> at the point of contact in landing. [...] The speeds represent 1.2 times power-off
> stall speeds for each flap setting.

Hypothetically, one could touch down at the stall speed, but it's probably more realistic to use the factor of 1.2 times stall speed here.

However, these speeds are airspeeds. To calculate the ground speed, we need to subtract the headwind component. The video says it was up to 50 kt, but one cannot always get that. Some comments under the video note that a modern aircraft carrier can always achieve 32 kt, when travelling into the wind.

Let's plug in a few numbers to see how much kinetic energy we get:

| Weight | Airspeed | Headwind | Energy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 75 000 lbs | 81 kt (Stall) | 50 kt | 4.3 MJ |
| 75 000 lbs | 97 kt | 50 kt | 9.9 MJ |
| 75 000 lbs | 97 kt | 32 kt | 19.0 MJ |
| **85 000 lbs** | **97 kt** | **50 kt** | **11.3 MJ** |
| **121 000 lbs** | **104 kt** | **50 kt** | **21.2 MJ** |
| 130 000 lbs | 89 kt (Stall) | 50 kt | 12.0 MJ |
| 130 000 lbs | 107 kt | 50 kt | 25.4 MJ |
| 130 000 lbs | 107 kt | 32 kt | 43.9 MJ |

<sup>(Airspeed is touchdown speed read from the graph, or stall speed without the safety factor of 1.2)</sup>

While megajoules sounds like quite a lot, these numbers are surprisingly small, mostly due to the relatively slow ground speed after subtracting the headwind. For reference: an A380 RTO corresponds to about 1.7 GJ according to [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/33850/33692).

**Where did it all go?**

Usually, most energy is dissipated by the wheel brakes, which should be more than capable of absorbing this energy (a single brake on the A380 can absorb 120 MJ). However, the C130 can also use reverse thrust during landing:

> Reverse thrust is applied by moving the throttles from FLIGHT IDLE to GROUND IDLE, and then into REVERSE range in coordination with nosewheel steering.

<sup>([C130 Flight Manual](https://www.docdroid.com/nOy1Uqo/uscg-lockheed-c-130-flight-manual-pdf) - 2-55 - Normal Landing)</sup>

This could further reduce the energy going into brakes, but since the video shows the C-130 stopping very quickly, there was likely not much time spent in reverse.

Comment: If not too troublesome, you could edit the actual weights  used in the tests into this answer, as they are mentioned in the Dark Skies video linked in the question.

Comment: @Jpe61 Thanks, I hadn't seen those. I included them into the table.

Comment: No math in the "where did it go" section?) I added landing roll distances to the question.

Comment: @Pilothead - Even with the landing roll numbers I don’t think there’s enough info to determine the ratio of braking power and reverse thrust. What *can* be said is that the energy dissipated by the reverse thrust goes into accelerating air molecules while the energy dissipated by the brakes is transferred to the boat (except for the energy that is converted to heat in the brakes themselves and I suppose some to the abrasion of the tires)